# ValueError in adding a conditioned extra column

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement, valueerror

I ran into an issue while using a conditioned function in order to create a new column in my dataframe.

While using the defined function to split the text based on an if statement the error that returned is the ValueError:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.

```py
    def split_name(Name):
        if (test_data['Tussenvoegsel'].str.len() != 0) :
            temp = str(re.findall(r'(\.[^.]*)$', Name))
            return (temp[3:100])
        else :
            return ("")
    
    test_data['Achternaam'] = test_data['Naam'].apply(lambda x: split_name(x))
```

Dataframe column where it's applied to is:

```
                       Naam Tussenvoegsel
0          Dhr. V. Andersen              
1  Mevr. J.C. van der Kosan       van der
2     Dhr. P.M.M. van Zomer           van
3     Mevr. M.J.J. Raimondo              
4     Mevr. E. van de Doorn        van de
```

Example of the expected outcome:

```
                       Naam Tussenvoegsel Achternaam
0          Dhr. V. Andersen               Andersen
1  Mevr. J.C. van der Kosan       van der 
2     Dhr. P.M.M. van Zomer           van 
3     Mevr. M.J.J. Raimondo               Raimondo              
4     Mevr. E. van de Doorn        van de
```

I've tried the split method, tried it without and with lambda, but I don't get it working.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use `if (len(Name) != 0)`, there might be a vectorial solution to your problem though, please provide a sample dataset and the matching expected output

Comment: @mozway, thanks, already helps, but the dependency should be based on another column than the manipulation, how can that be done?

Comment: The logic is unclear, you want to extract the name except if starting with van/van de/van der?

Comment: you should run `test_data.apply(split_name)` (instead of `test_data['Naam'].apply(split_name)` and then you get full `row` in function `def split_name(row):` and you can use `row['Tussenvoegsel']` and `row["Naam"]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, it reminded me to build the function with two arguments hence change the input into: 

```def split_name(tussenvoegsel, Name):
    if (len(tussenvoegsel) == 0) :
       temp = str(re.findall(r'(\.[^.]*)$', Name)) 
       return (temp[3:-2])
    else:
        temp = re.search(tussenvoegsel, Name)
        tempint = int(temp.end())
        return(Name[tempint:100])
    test_data['Achternaam'] = test_data.apply(lambda x: split_name(x['Tussenvoegsel'], x['Naam']),axis=1)
```